# Reasons to colonize Mars and what would we do there?

Tags: mars

There was another question that was excluded that opened up this can of warms in my head. I have some ideas on why go and what to do there but I wanted to open up and have other ideas coming in for a properly formulated question. (I hope)

Comment: This question is just too broad to be useful for this site. Try narrowing the focus of this, and you might have something useful. Also, read [The Case For Mars](http://amzn.to/2fOHXPc)

Answer (score 3):

Mars colonization idea suffers from the lack of economic case for it. It's not clear how to make it profitable. If there was an economic case for colonization, things would've been moving much faster.

There are several non-economic reasons for Mars colonization:

- aspirational - humanity has a drive to explore and expand
- survival - a hypothetical planetary scale disaster wouldn't extinguish humankind if we were dispersed among planets
- romantic - "a new frontier"

One of the most forceful and persistent advocates of Mars colonization is Robert Zubrin. He published his first book, [The Case for Mars](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0684827573), more than 20 years ago, in which he attempted to answer these questions. His argument was not simple. In my opinion, he didn't provide a clear economic case for colonization. He builds the case essentially by analogy with colonization of America. I understood his reasoning this way:
In the very long term, there will be self-sustaining human civilization on Mars because Mars has sufficient and diverse resources needed to sustain it (think USA of 19-20 centuries). In the long but a bit shorter term, Mars could provide agricultural and other commodities to Asteroid Belt mining in a triangle trade arrangement (hi-tech from Earth to Mars, commodities from Mars to the Belt, raw materials from the Belt to Earth). This is equivalent to Europe-Americas-Caribbean triangle of 18th century. Note that this assumes that Belt mining operations will be profitable - so far, a big IF. Medium term - big unknown. Short term - Earth has enough resources to start the colonization program. This will probably be proven true at least as far as first steps go - it's highly likely that manned expeditions to Mars are going to happen within decades, not centuries.

This still leaves open the question about what will sustain the Mars colony economically (what will be the equivalent of gold, silver and furs that Americas exported to Europe). Malthusian fears that various resources are running out on Earth are not as popular any more, so there is no pressing need to go to other planets to mine their mineral wealth. Martian rocks as novelties might pay for about 1 crewed expedition, but not for sustained colony. There may be other ideas out there, but I haven't seen enough yet. Maybe cheaper launch and space travel costs will help create unexpected innovative ideas.